# Using Kotlin as RestAPI parser for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, kotlin

I am currently going to write an Android and iOS app, which is heavily based on communication with RestAPI server.
My goal is to write communication, parsing, etc. only once. I've heard about *Kotlin shared library*, yet wasn't able to get it working yet.
Before wasting more time on trying to get that working, is that the way to go?
What other ways would you suggest to me?
**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably Kotlin MultiPlatform Projects. Check out https://ktor.io, which allows you to write networking code only once. Also checkout https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization for JSON serialization.